# Keyboard shortcut to extend clip duration (without changing speed) in order to fill gap for J-Cut in Premiere

Tags: premiere, automation, keyboard-shortcut

I'm trying to automate away the mouse (using Autohotkey) during the editing process. All regular edits are now keyboard-only except the J-Cut. Basically I want to fill the video gap in the following example:

[image]

I can easily do it with the mouse by extending the duration of the video on the left:

[image]

How can I do this with just the keyboard (and help of Autohotkey if needed)?

Answer (score 2):

Shift-Q does it - as per the [following StackExchange answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/16339/1460) which refers to images but this applies to videos too:

**Shift-Q** - extend previous edit to playhead